# Проблема с постами на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Помогите разобраться с постами на *WordPress*. Нужно чтобы выводилось `3` последних поста на главную страницу и для каждого поста я могла указать количество слов которое там должно отображаться.

Например:

- для первого поста необходимо 16 слов
- для второго поста 22 слова
- для третьего - 19

Проблема состоит в том чтобы указывать разную длинну постов. Я пробовала плагин "*recent posts extended*" но там можно указать длинну постов но она будет она одна для всех.

Или может я могу другой какой-нибуль виджет использовать для этих целей.
Спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для этого же достаточно в посте [`<-- more -->`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content) указать и будет обрезаться как вам угодно.

Comment: <-- more -->  просто не работает, он не обрезает пост, и кликабельной кнопки more собственно нет.

Comment: значит вы как-то не так его добавляете, у меня он работает нормально, при вставке в пост было открыто визуальное форматирование или текстовое? Т.е. если вставить в пост - тег становится виден или нет? Если виден, значит не так вставили, если не виден, значит как-то не так посты отображаете

Comment: Возможно я действительно не правильно добавляю его. Я пишу 
A my new postA my new postA my new postA my new postA my new 
<!--more-->
FFFFFFFFmy new postA my new postA my new postA my new post
 Но все равно вижу весь пост.
Я пробовала и текстовое форматирование  и визуальное, без результатов.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно чтобы эту возможность поддерживал шаблон. Разделть текст поста по тегу `<!--more-->` можно при помощи функции [`get_extended()`](http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_extended).

**Дополнено**

Воспользоваться этой функцией можно или прямо в шаблоне, или в файле `function.php`. Поскольку вы выводите список постов на главной, это происходит вне основного цикла вывода постов. Скорее всего в шаблоне главной страницы (или в `function.php`) сделан дополнительный запрос, в котором возвращаются нужные вам три последние записи.

Для вывода отрывка до разделителя по `ID` поста написать такую функцию в `function.php` (или вставить весь код в соответствующее место шаблона):

```
function the_short_content( $ID ) {
    $post = get_post( $ID );
    $content_parts = get_extended( $post->post_content );
    $short_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content_parts['main'] );
    echo $short_content;
}
```

Потом можно вызвать ее в шаблоне вместо `the_content()`.

Comment: А можно подробнее про функцию, куда именно ее нужно добавить? В function.php

Comment: @Mariana Дополнил ответ